# Points for members in a network who invites non users

Tags: php, zend-framework, joomla

I have created a rule in Jomsocial to award points for member who invites non users.. But now the problem is that...The points are awarded even

1. when the member enters "invite friends" page
2. points awarded when member sent email to a user(never checks whether user is a member in network or not)

How can I restrict this?

I need to award points only when the email is sent to a "non-user" or when the non-user clicks the link in the email body.

Currently this is used in `components/com_community/libraries/mailq.php` inside the function:

```
public function send( $total = 100 )
{
    $mailqModel = CFactory::getModel( 'mailq' );
    $userModel  = CFactory::getModel( 'user' );
    $mails      = $mailqModel->get( $total, true );
    $jconfig    = JFactory::getConfig();
    $mailer     = JFactory::getMailer();
    $config     = CFactory::getConfig();

    $senderEmail  = $jconfig->getValue('mailfrom');
    $senderName   = $jconfig->getValue('fromname');
```

The code below is used to award points. I think some more conditions need to be added to make it validated:

```
if($senderName)
{
    $JomSocialCheck = JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'userpoints.php';

    if ( file_exists($JomSocialCheck)) {
        include_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'userpoints.php');

        CuserPoints::assignPoint('com_user.add.friend');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My grandpa used to say: "when you're shouting - I hear you, when you're talking - I'm listening..." ;)

One of the two problems, I believe you can solve by modifying your code as follows:

```
if($senderName)
{
    $JomSocialCheck = JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'userpoints.php';

if ( file_exists($JomSocialCheck)) {
    include_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'userpoints.php');

    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    if($user->id) {
    // he's already a user - do nothing
    }
    else {
      CuserPoints::assignPoint('com_user.add.friend');
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: so maybe you were wrong and this is not the place to add validations ;)

Comment: but is it possible to add the above code under here..                                                                                                                                      if(!$validate){ //email is blocked by user settings
    $mailqModel->markEmailStatus($row->id, 2);
   }
   else{
    $mailqModel->markSent($row->id);
   }